For what values ​of s does the following integral converge?
For what values ​​of s does the following integral converge?
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^s + x}}dx
$$
I have tried to do it by comparing integrals for the different cases of s (s>0, s = 0, s<0), but I can't get anywhere, I would like to know if there is any other idea.
In wolframalpha I have seen that this integral converges for values ​​of s>4.

Please describe your efforts at solving this, this site is not here to just do your work for you

A comparison test shows for all $s>4$ the integral converges.

If $p \le 1$, then
$$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + x}} \text {d} x \ge \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {x + x}} \text {d} x = \int_{1}^{N} \frac {\sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {2}} \text {d} x = \frac {N \sqrt {N} - 1}{3 \, / \sqrt {2}}.$$
If $1 < p \le 2$, then
$$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + x}} \text {d} x > \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + {x}^{p}}} \text {d} x \ge \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {2 {x}^{2}}} \text {d} x = \int_{1}^{N} \frac {1}{\sqrt {2}} \text {d} x = \frac {N - 1}{\sqrt {2}}.$$
If $2 < p \le 4$, then
$$ \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + x}} \text {d} x > \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + {x}^{p}}} \text {d} x \ge \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {2 {x}^{4}}} \text {d} x = \int_{1}^{N} \frac {1}{\sqrt {2} x} \text {d} x = \frac {\ln \left( N \right)}{\sqrt {2}}.$$
If $p > 4$, then
$$\begin{align} \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p} + x}} \text {d} x < \int_{1}^{N} \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{p}}} \text {d} x & = \int_{1 / N}^{1} \frac {\sqrt {{x}^{p}}}{x} \cdot \frac {1}{{x}^{2}} \text {d} x \\ & < \int_{0}^{1} \frac {\sqrt {{x}^{p}}}{x} \cdot \frac {1}{{x}^{2}} \text {d} x = \int_{0}^{1} {x}^{p / 2 - 3} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{p / 2 - 2}. \end{align}$$
(Let $N \to \infty$.)

Thank you very much. I was making a mistake by comparing based on the cases of .
